# SelfControl like app for Android

Tags: android

[SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com/index.html) is a great app on Mac, once you started it, there's nothing you can do to stop it, whether you deleted the app or restart the computer.

> SelfControl is a free and open-source application for Mac OS X (10.5
>   or above) that lets you block your own access to distracting websites,
>   your mail servers, or anything else on the Internet. Just set a period
>   of time to block for, add sites to your blacklist, and click "Start."
>   Until that timer expires, you will be unable to access those
>   sites--even if you restart your computer or delete the application.

Is there any SelfControl like app on Android?

---

**Update**

Maybe the *"Especially this app would also work even if **you delete the app or restart the smartphone.**"*restriction is too much, so I reduce those restrictions.

Comment: So you want to restrict Internet access only?

Comment: @unor That's right.

Comment: The SelfControl [dev](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/wiki/FAQ) doesn't seem to be aware of any Android equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some impressive application for Self Controlling but this App might help you waste less time ...

[Self Control for Study](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.specialj.selfcontrol) Or [Self Control Plus for Study](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.specialj.selfcontrolplus) *(Premium + Ad Free)*

From Apps page

> This app help people to reduce intemperate use of smart phones. For a
>   specified period of time the execution of apps banned in order to help
>   to focus a little more. (Basic telephone functions, such as phone call
>   and SMS, are always executable.)

Key Features

1. When you execute Apps for a specified period of time, phone screen will switch to studying time display automatically.
2. After setting weekly and daily, graphs can be displayed.
3. Specific apps that you set can be always executable.

---

Some Screenshots of the application

[image]
[image]
[image]

<sup>Credits: Google PlayStore Self Control for Study Page</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for blocking youtube as any apps you can control using app lock and putting a password on that. Tough password so that you have to look to type not by remembering. If that is the case then use v browser for android as it only allow to search and read information.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vnspeak.vbrowser&hl=en_IN&gl=US